# Redis Using HSET to store an object

Tags: node.js, redis

I used to use HMSET to store an object after flattening it using the npm flat module. So something like this:

```
let bio = {
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Doe'
    },
    goal: {
        desc: 'TO BE THE VERY BEST, LIKE NO ONE EVER WAS!',
        test: 'TO CATCH THEM IS MY REAL TEST -- ',
        cause: 'TO TRAIN THEM IS MY CAUUUUUSE!'
    },
    hobbies: [ 'making coffee', 'making low carb recipes', 'soccer' ],
    'education.college': {
        name: 'Baruch'
    },
    'hobbiesAsObject[]': {
        '0': 'making coffee',
        '1': 'making low carb recipes',
        sport: 'Baseball'
    },
    age: 44
};

let flatBio = flat(bio);
let hmSetAsyncBio = await client.hmsetAsync('bio', flatBio);
```

But I read that HMSET is considered deprecated, When I try to use HSET in this same fashion it does not work. I know I can just JSON.stringfy it and store that using just a normal SET but I'd like to be able to increment fields in my object.  This is how I did it previously:

```
const incrAge = await client.hincrbyAsync('bio', 'age', 1);
```

So my question is, how can I do this using HSET?  I keep trying different things but it doesn't seem to be working. Some examples I have seen show looping through the object (this is one example I saw https://thisdavej.com/guides/redis-node/node/hashes.html) and using HSET on each item, but I have nested objects and it seems like it's more of a PITA now than it previously was.  There has to be a simpler way to do it no?

Redis server version: 5.0.7
Node Version: 12.14.0
node-redis (npm module) version: 0.1.7
redis (npm module) version: 3.0.2

Error when I replace

```
let hmSetAsyncBio = await client.hmsetAsync('bio', flatBio);
```

with

```
let hmSetAsyncBio = await client.hsetAsync('bio', flatBio);
```

Error: node_redis: The HSET command contains a invalid argument type.
Only strings, dates and buffers are accepted. Please update your code to use valid argument types.

Comment: Not ideal but as a band-aid solution retrieve the object, increment, push changed back into Redis if you just need it working off the top of my head

Comment: As of Redis 4.0.0, HSET is variadic, it works for me. Note the reply is integer vs HMSET string. Please add your Redis version, node-redis version and the error you're getting when using HSET

Comment: @LeoMurillo Added Redis, node-redis and error to op

Comment: @Novice did you consider using the Redis Module - RedisJSON?